# Can I use the files inside the Assets folder without having a context?

Tags: android, android-assets

I have a file in the assets folder of my app.  Is there any way I can use this file without having a context instance?

Comment: What do you want to do with that file ?

Comment: i think u can not use the asset folder with out context...u can just pass your context as parameter in class construcor

Comment: As the other answers/comments pointed out you need a context-instance. However Activity, Service, broadcastlister and many other classes inherit from context so you can use these as context.

Answer (score 0):

Nope you need a context.  Note that you should always have access to a context in your app except under some static contexts.  As another poster pointed out, if you require context access from within utility classes/methods, you simply need to make Context a parameter of the method(s).